# Visual studio 2013 freezes while publishing a cloud service

Tags: visual-studio, azure-cloud-services

For cloud service deployment , when I hit publish, visual studio goes unresponsive. No error and if you try to click on visual studio it says visual studio is busy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix that worked for me- Go to server explorer, Go to Azure node and right click and connect to a Microsoft Azure subscription. Reenter your credentials and connect and try to publish again.

Comment: @NickHeppleston +1! Restart Visual Studio once if it doesn't work even after entering credentials again.